# Groovy pattern matching automatically adding anchor tags?

Tags: regex, groovy, switch-statement

I'm trying to do some pattern matching in a `switch` statement, and it seems like start/end anchor tags are automatically being added -

```
String s = "abc";

switch(s){
  case ~/b/:
    ....//doesn't trigger
    break;
  case ~/abc/:
    ....//does trigger
    break;
}
```

Is there anyway I can get the partial match to work without adding `.*`s?

Comment: That's kinda goofy... should work

Comment: Would match with `~/\wb\w/` or `~/\w+b\w+/` as `switch` evaluates pattern matching (`==~`) instead of String contains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, switch is checking for complete matches of the string. So, you can pass a closure to it.

```
switch(s) {
  case { it =~ /b/ }:
    // do something
    break;
  case ~/abc/:
    // do something
    break;
}
```

[**Ideone Demo**](http://ideone.com/VG2STt)